# Work out an algorithm on Codality

Tags: c++, algorithm

http://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/tape_equilibrium

> Minimize the value |(A[0] + ... + A[P-1]) - (A[P] + ... + A[N-1])|.
>
> MPORTANT!
>
> Make sure to handle all corner cases and large inputs efficiently. Assume nothing, trust no one!

So I have tried the brute force apporach, but I got 66% percent of correction, and I failed a test case where there are only two numbers..

```
int solution(vector<int> &a) {
   int sumLeft = 0;
     int sumRight = 0;
     int minDiff = 9999999;
    for(int b=0; b< a.size();b++)
    { 
            
    sumLeft+=a[b];
    sumRight = 0;       
    for (int j = b+1; j < a.size();j++)
            
    {
        sumRight+=a[j];
            
    }

    int diff = abs(sumLeft - sumRight);

    if ( diff < minDiff )
    {

        minDiff = diff;
    }
    
    }

  return minDiff;
}
```

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose of your function and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
int solution(vector<int> &a) {
    int sumLeft = 0;
    int sumRight = 0;

    for(int b=0; b< a.size();b++)
        sumRight += a[b];

    int minDiff = sumRight;

    for(int b=0; b< a.size();b++)
    {
        sumLeft  += a[b];
        sumRight -= a[b];

        int diff = abs(sumLeft - sumRight);

        if ( diff < minDiff )
        {
            minDiff = diff;
        }
    }

    return minDiff;
}
```

Comment: This makes the algorithm more efficient, but it will still fail if the numbers are very large.

Comment: Edited - initial `minDiff` calculated differently.

Comment: I'd like to init `minDiff` with `MAX_INT`, but it might be undefined; try using `(int)(~0U >> 1)` then.

Comment: how did you come up with that solution? should I study discrete mathematics ?  it's really clever

Comment: Which one solution? If you mean the code organization, it's quite simple: every shift of a partitioning point removes `a[b]` from one part and adds it to the other, so you can modify both sums incrementally, just need to calculate one of them in advance. What concerns the initialization expression, it is maximum `int` for U2 code: all bits set except the leftmost one (a sign bit). I achieve it by taking `unsigned` zero `0U`, then negating it `~0U` (which produces all bits 1) and shifting right by one `(~0U>>1)` which makes the sign bit zero. Then I cast to `(int)`. Done.

Comment: I made a mistake in one of comments above, wrote `MAX_INT`, should be `INT_MAX`.

Comment: should sumRight start from index 1 not 0 ?

Comment: May be. But there's no specific conditions given, so I assume that input [–1, +1] is possible, in which case the answer *might be* 'the left part empty (with empty sum by convention equal zero) and right part of the whole array with sum –1+1=0'.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure to handle all corner cases and large inputs efficiently. Assume nothing, trust no one!

```
int minDiff = 9999999;
```

What if you have the numbers `10^17` and `10^16`? The minimum difference is then larger than what you initialize `minDiff` with.

This would also explain why you are failing a test case with just two numbers in it.

I would at least use 64 bit integers, although the problem statement implies that the values could exceed even that. Which is bad news if you want to use C++ to solve it.

Comment: I changed minDiff to INT_MAX still it fails for two numbers

Comment: WRONG ANSWER double 
two elements 
got 0 expected 2000

Answer (score 0):

This solution receive 100% pass.
The tricky moment in this task is taking account that two partitions must be non empty.

```
#include <algorithm>

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    auto n= 0;
    for(auto& ai: A) {
        ai+= n;
        n= ai;
    }
    auto f_diff=
    [&A](int ai) {
        return abs(A.back() - (ai + ai));
    };
    auto min_diff= f_diff(A.front());
    for_each(next(begin(A)), prev(end(A)), [&](int ai) {
        auto diff= f_diff(ai);
        if(diff < min_diff) {
            min_diff= diff;
        }
    });
    return min_diff;

    // write your code in C++11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution will give you 100% in both coverage and performance in C#

```
public int solution(int[] A)
        {
            long minDifference = Int32.MaxValue;
            long bottomSum = 0;
            long topSum = 0;

            long total = A.Sum();

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length-1; i++)
            {
                bottomSum += A[i];
                topSum =(long) (total - bottomSum);

                if (Math.Abs(bottomSum - topSum) <= minDifference) 
                {
                    minDifference = Math.Abs(bottomSum - topSum);
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(minDifference);
        }
```